# Regarding spatial resolution conversion programming - bmp image

Tags: c, resolution, spatial, bmp

I want to ask something about simple spatial resolution manipulating just by using c language. I have done my programming below, it managed to be compiled but for some reasons the program stucked in the middle when I try to run it. Really hope you guys can help. I am extremely beginner on this.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define width 640
#define height 581

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp; 
    unsignedchar header[54]; 
    unsignedchar img_work[width][height][3]; 
    char input_file[128],output_file[128]; 
    int v, h, w, i, c, s, ave_w[width], ave_h[height], average_h, average_w;

    /*------------Reading image------------*/

    printf("Enter name of the file¥n---");
    scanf("%s",input_file);
    printf("The file that would be processed is %s.¥n", input_file);
    fp=fopen(input_file,"rb"); 
    fread(header,1,54,fp); 
    fread(img_work,1,width*height*3,fp); 
    fclose(fp);

     /*------------Spatial Resolution Program------------*/

    printf ("enter level of spatialization-- ");
    scanf ("%d", &v);

    for (i=0; i<v; i++) {
        s = s + s;
    }

    for(c=0; c<3; c++){
        for(h=0; h<height; h++){
            for(w=0; w<width; w=w+s){
                average_w = 0;

                for (i=0; i<s; i++) {
                    ave_w = img_work[w+i][h][c] / s;
                    average_w = average_w + ave_w;
                }

                for (i=0; i<width; i=i+s) {
                    img_work[w+i][h][c] = average_w;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(c=0; c<3; c++){
        for(w=0; w<width; w++){
            for(h=0; h<height; h=h+s){
                average_h = 0;
                for (i=0; i<s; i++) {
                    ave_h = img_work[w][h+i][c] / s;
                    average_h = average_h + ave_h;
                }
                for (i=0; i<height; i=i+s) {
                    img_work[w][h+i][c] = average_h;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /*------------Writing File------------*/

    printf("Enter the name of the file that would be saved.¥n---");
    scanf("%s",output_file); 
    printf("Name of the file that would be saved is %s.¥n",output_file);
    fp=fopen(output_file,"wb"); 
    fwrite(header,1,54,fp); 
    fwrite(img_work,1,width*height*3,fp); 
    fclose(fp);

    printf("End.¥n");

    return 0;
}
```

I am really a beginner, so, sorry if this is lacking too much.

Comment: Is this the actual code you compiled? As is, it won't compile. For example, you use `unsignedchar`, which should be two words. And you assign to `ave_w` instead of `ave_w[i]`. Could you please verify that the code is the one you could compile?

Comment: When you assign `s = s + s;`, `s` is uninitialised. You want to set it to `s = 1;` or some such before the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

- `s` is uninitialised. Hence, when you access its value in the assignment `s = s + s`, the result is undefined. `s` may even be negative. Initialise it: `s = 1`;
- You've got the representation of your image wrong. You read the pixel data verbatim from the file. The BMP format is row major, so your pixel data should be `img_work[height][width][3]` and all accesses should have their first and second dimensions swapped.
- The BMP format also requires padding at the end of each row. Your fixed-size width of 640 doesn't require it, but it's worth keeping in mind when you want to make your implementation more general.
- You don't really need the auxiliary variables `ave_w` and `ave_h`. Most importantly, you don't need them to be arrays.
- Your height isn't evenly divisible by `s`. That means that in the last pass through the loop, `h + i` will go out of bounds. (The same applies to the width, but the value 640 is safe up to at least a level of 7.) You could calculate an "actual `s`" that would be adjusted for the top and right sides.
- When you calculate the average, it is better to sum the values first and then divide by `s` once. You are dealing with integers and integer division truncates. For example `3/4` is zero. Consequently, `(3/4 + 3/4 + 3/4 + 3+4)` is also zero, but `(3 + 3 + 3 + 3) / 4` is 3. You can notice the effect for larger levels of reduction, where a predominantly white imagfe becomes darker if you divide on summation.

Here's a program based on yours, that puts the points raised above into practice:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define width 640
#define height 581

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp; 
    unsigned char header[54]; 
    unsigned char img_work[height][width][3]; 
    char input_file[128];
    char output_file[128]; 
    int v, h, w, i, c, s;

    /*------------Reading image------------*/

    printf("Enter name of the file\n---");
    scanf("%s",input_file);
    printf("The file that would be processed is %s.\n", input_file);
    fp=fopen(input_file,"rb"); 
    fread(header,1,54,fp); 
    fread(img_work,1,width*height*3,fp); 
    fclose(fp);

     /*------------Spatial Resolution Program------------*/

    printf("enter level of spatialization-- ");
    scanf("%d", &v);

    s = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < v; i++) {
        s = s + s;
    }

    for (c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
        for (h = 0; h < height; h++) {
            for (w = 0; w < width; w = w + s) {
                int average_w = 0;
                int ss = s;

                if (w + ss > width) ss = width % s;

                for (i = 0; i < ss; i++) {
                    average_w = average_w + img_work[h][w + i][c];
                }

                for (i = 0; i < ss; i++) {
                    img_work[h][w + i][c] = average_w / ss;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
        for (w = 0; w < width; w++) {
            for (h = 0; h < height; h = h + s) {
                int average_h = 0;
                int ss = s;

                if (h + ss > height) ss = height % s;

                for (i = 0; i < ss; i++) {
                    average_h = average_h + img_work[h + i][w][c];
                }
                for (i = 0; i < ss; i++) {
                    img_work[h + i][w][c] = average_h / ss;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /*------------Writing File------------*/

    printf("Enter the name of the file that would be saved.\n---");
    scanf("%s",output_file); 
    printf("Name of the file that would be saved is %s.\n",output_file);
    fp=fopen(output_file,"wb"); 
    fwrite(header,1,54,fp); 
    fwrite(img_work,1,width*height*3,fp); 
    fclose(fp);

    printf("End.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

That's still a quick-and-dirty program with fixed image sizes. It doesn't enforce that the actual size of the image, which can be read from the header, and the fixed sizes match or that the colour depth is the same or that you even get enough pixel data, for which you should check the return value of `fread`.

Comment: Thank you so much. The language barrier here (right now I am learning programming in Japan with the subject in Japanese, so I cannot understand much, even English is not my native language) make things a lot harder. I have tried execute the program on Xcode and got this error on inline `fread(header,1,54,fp);` line. It said **thread 1 exc_bad_access (code=1, address=0x68)**

Comment: @Hafiz: that is (most likely) a result of *not verifying the input*. You need to verify if opening the file was successful.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? I am sorry because I am really a beginner and not very good in computer terms and stuff. Will really do a lot more study. And I have tried run the program just using the terminal, the program could be run (although some code still need to be fixed. Will work on it). It seems that using Xcode although fancier, make things a lot more complicated. And then since the file in my university is using Japanese font in the original programming file which I have copied to my Mac here, things get a lot messier. @jongware

Comment: @HafizHilmanMohammadSofian: All system calls such as `fopen`, `fread`, `scanf` have a way to indicate an error, usually a special return value. It is good practice to check them. At the moment, your program is a "throwaway" program that can handle 640x581 pixel BMP images with 24-bit colour depth. You assume these values without enforcing them. A proper program should check these facts and exit with an error message, for example.

Comment: @MOehm Hmm. I don't really quite understand. Can you give me an example?